# TeamCity - Nuget package restore and RequireConsent

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, nuget

A TeamCity build fails. It is failing to update a NuGet package to a particular version, which is available on a feed actually provided by TeamCity itself.

> E:\TeamCity-BuildAgent\work\62023563850993a7\Web.nuget\nuget.targets(88, 9): Unable to find version '1.0.17.0' of package 'MarkLogicManager40'.
>
> E:\TeamCity-BuildAgent\work\62023563850993a7\Web.nuget\nuget.targets(88, 9): error MSB3073: The command ""E:\TeamCity-BuildAgent\work\62023563850993a7\Web.nuget\nuget.exe" install "E:\TeamCity-BuildAgent\work\62023563850993a7\CompanyImagesMvc.Tests\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "E:\TeamCity-BuildAgent\work\62023563850993a7\Web\ "" exited with code 1.

Possibly its able to run NuGet and connect to the feed and not find the version (its there) or its not running because the `RequireConsent` option is in the command line.

Does TeamCity construct this command line or MSBuild? How can I make it so it doesn't require consent?

Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that once I'd enabled/setup the custom NuGet feed path, see link:

[NuGet Package Restore cannot find package, has no Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151709/teamcity-nuget-package-restore-cannot-find-package-has-no-source/17152514#17152514)

it all worked, the RequireConsent was a red-herring.

Comment: Turns out that my teamcity nuget feed user didn't have project viewer rights.

Answer (score 0):

That command line looks like it is being output from MSBuild when your solution is being built.

One way to enable package restore in TeamCity is to create an [env.EnableNuGetPackageRestore environment variable](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) and set its value to True. You can set that in the Build Parameters for your Team City project.