# TeamCity Nuget Feed does not pick up latest Packages from a build

Tags: teamcity

So we have a TeamCity server that builds our code and we have some "NuGet Pack" steps to pack our dependancies. Now after switching routers at the office The localfeed picks up packages from previous builds and not the latest versions. We publish the build artifacts and put them in build/packages. Could someone please shed some light as too where nuget looks for the packages we created and how can we fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity stores the packages on the server and makes them available via the URL(s) shown in *Administration -> Server Configuration -> NuGet*. [See also.](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/12/setting-up-teamcity-as-a-native-nuget-server/)

> Now after switching routers at the office ...

Assuming nothing else has changed, and that this was all working before, you should simply need to ensure that your build agents can route to the host(s) defined in those URLs.

**EDIT:** There are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548324/how-to-add-the-custom-nuget-feed-to-teamcity-build) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151709/nuget-package-restore-cannot-find-package-has-no-source) which can help you to understand the ways a build agent can be configured to look for packages at a given URL.